# WSDL exposing methods with and without security

Tags: web-services, wsdl, weblogic

Is it possible to have a single WSDL exposing few methods that must be accessed securely over HTTPS and few methods that can be accessed with HTTP.

Currently we have a webservice that runs on Weblogic 10.3. We have enabled security for this in the WSDL itself (X509 Certificate, Signed and Encrypted Parts). Now we would like to enhance the functionality of this webservice and add a few methods to be used by internal applications running on different servers within the same network. We want these methods be accessed with HTTP.
Is it possible for a single webservice to service both HTTP and HTTPS requests?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a conceptual point of view, yes. A WSDL consists of two parts, the abstract and concrete part. The abstract part defines messages, groups them to operations and then to portTypes, which represent the public interface. In the concrete part, these interfaces are then bound to a transport protocol (< binding >) and exposed at an endpoint (< port > and < service >). Thus, you can simple define two bindings and services for a single portType, which will result in having two service endpoints with different QoS and/or transports for the same public interface.